# Why can't an user-defined function take integer arguments and return integer?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The following user-defined function cannot be used in the worksheet. When I type

```
=Add2(1,1)
```

it returns #REF.

```
Function add2(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    add2 = x + y
End Function
```

If I change Integer to Double, only then it works. Why can't integer be used? Thank you.

Comment: Name it `Function MYADD(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer` and it should work.

Comment: The problem is here, that ADD2 is also a range... I really don't know however, why it works when you change the output to double.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost pls post your answer, so this question can be closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here, that ADD2 is also a range, but why it works when you change the output to double, I don't know.

Comment: You have rightly pointed out my careless mistake. Thank you very much.